# Javascript: Object attribute declaration from variable

Tags: javascript

I am aware I can use another object's property as a key to declare a property of the object, like so:

```
var object1 = {
    myAttr: 'myName'
};
var object2 = {};
var object2[object1.myAttr] = 'myValue';
```

Then we have `object2.myName == 'myValue'`.

How would I go about doing that directly in the object's declaration? Something like that:

```
var object1 = {
    myAttr: 'myName'
};
var object2 = {
    object1.myattr: 'myValue'
};
```

But that actually works.

Comment: You wouldn't, it's that simple !

Comment: Bummer. Alright then, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could change your code a bit and do this:

```
var object1 = {
     myAttr: 'myName'
};

var object2 = new function(){
    this[object1.myAttr] = 'myValue'
}();
```

You can evolve this and pass object1 as an attribute to the object2 function and things go on...

Answer (score -1):

You can do using eval function of javascript

```
var object1 = {   myAttr: 'myName' };
eval("var object2 = { "+object1.myAttr+": 'myValue' }");
console.log(object2.myName);
```